# Can't find newline in csv string

Tags: php, asp.net, csv

Using `file_get_contents()` I retrieve CSV data from an external URL. In this data there are breaks visible for every new record in the CSV. However, when I try to explode the lines, I only get one item in my array, containing the full CSV dataset. This is the code I use:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://example.url/csvdata.asp?id=20'); // has 12 records
$rows = explode("\n", $data);
echo count($rows); // returns 1
```

Could this have to do with that an ASP script generates the CSV? Do they use other new line characters?

Comment: ASP runs off of Windows, so use `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- If \n is present strind should be splitted

Comment: @splash58 *10-4* ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` can work but there are more ways for new lines. This should work:

```
$lines = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $data);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works! I will accept this as a correct answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: `preg_split('/\R/', $вфеф);`

Answer (score 2):

Use **[file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)** and let PHP handle the new lines

> file — Reads entire file into an array

You can simply do

```
$rows = file('http://example.url/csvdata.asp?id=20');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with mine. I found this somewhere on SO:

```
$rows = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
```

`PHP_EOL` finds the end of the line.